# Is Native API SDK for Here Maps for Android SDK available now?

Tags: android, maps, here-api

In china mainland, google maps is not available from time to time, so I want to use here maps on Android SDK, but there is only a contact me link on the official guide.

So Is Native API SDK for Here Maps for Android SDK available now?  And how it was charged.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/overview.html

here you can get all the required information regarding the HERE-SDK for android and iOS,

for getting the SDK you will have to contact the HERE team.